# White line appearing on all sides of web page

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I'm sorry I cannot show you the code, it is currently on my localhost.

I am pretty sure I have correctly typed the code because Netbeans doesn't show any errors. I am making my parents website for their charity, Enough to Spare. When I load the webpage though, there is a white line on all sides (although you can't see the top line because that div is white)
Here is a screenshot.
[image]
Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know why you've been down voted, decent question. I answered it the best I could without you providing any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you use a reset.css file before your own.css, so you start with a blank slate.

You could always add -

```
html { width:100%; height:100%; margin:0 padding:0; }
body { width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; }
```

http://www.cssreset.com/ - This is where I look to get my reset.css file

Thank you to [Dan Ovidiu Boncut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1820097/dan-ovidiu-boncut) for reminding me to put in margin:0; and padding:0;!

**Ninja edit**: Have you tried using the Chrome Developer Tools? You can play with the css using that. Right click on an element and click on inspect, there you can add new css styles and edit your current ones. It is a brilliant way to find solutions to your css issues... it also shows you what line in your css file you're at, so when you come to make the changes in file you know where to look straight away! :)

Comment: Plus margin:0 and padding:0 for each. This would be a good practice.

Comment: Thanks! That did it quite well, although I don't know why people would put default padding. Just to make people frustrated maybe?

Comment: I forgot to include margin and padding! DOH!

Answer (score 1):

In the CSS, try changing the `padding` of the container `<div>` to 0, because anything inside a `<div>` is also inside whatever padding it has, resulting in space between the padding and the border. Also try changing the `margin` to 0, because having a margin will result in space between the border and its container.

If you don't have a container `<div>`, or this didn't fix it, try setting the `padding` of the `<body>` tag to 0, because it's the outer-most container and might have default padding.

I also think there might be alternative ways to set background contents to ignore padding. Unfortunately, it's been a little while since I've worked in HTML and CSS, and I don't currently have time to experiment with that. But see what you can do with the above suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that NetBeans doesn't show errors doesn't mean your presentation is the way you want it to be.

Check your containing divs. Check for any margins and/or paddings that could cause spacing. Borders as well.
If all fails use a [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) and check again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy and paste the html and css involving your page elements, otherwise no one will be able to help you. Having your code on localhost has nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that solved this problem for me was adding

```
body {overflow-x: hidden;}
```

to my CSS file. Once this works, I guess you can remove:

```
html { width:100%; height:100%; margin:0px padding:0; }
body { width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; }
```

And also: quick tip for beginners: always use Command + Shift + R for a hard reload instead of a normal Command + R while testing solutions.

Comment: If this is the only thing that solved your problem, then you most likely didn't figure out what the actual problem is. Some element on your page is going outside the page width, most likely something using `position: absolute;` or `position: fixed;`. Remove the `overflow-x`, then start by deleting each top level element below the `body` element and see when it the scrollbar/white lines disappear. Reload the page and start again with the last element that made it go away.